# Displaying same time passed in while through time_passed function

Tags: php, while-loop, timestamp

I'm doing a `while()` and in it I use a function to display a prettier "time since posted", but for some reason, all of the results end up in the same "time passed" (the last result) when echoing it out

only the time will become the same, not the other content. Here's my code, trimmed down a bit:

```
<?php
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $dbboardname WHERE replyto = '' AND hidden = '' ORDER BY bump ASC LIMIT $pagenum, 20") OR die($db->error);
while($rowaaa = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $id = $rowaaa['id'];
    $textcontent = $rowaaa['textcontent'];
    $imageurl = $rowaaa['imageurl'];
    $name = $rowaaa['nameyes'];
    $timestamps = $rowaaa['timestamp'];
    $timestamps = time_passed($timestamps);
    $tripcode = $rowaaa['tripcode'];
?>
    <div class="post-index" data-postid="<?php echo($id); ?>" name="<?php echo($id); ?>" id="<?php echo($id); ?>">
        <div class="image-container-index">

            <?php if(!empty($imageurl)){ ?>
            <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo($id); ?>"><img src="<?php echo($imageurl); ?>" alt="image <?php echo($id); ?>" /></a>
            <?php }else{
            ?>
            <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo($id); ?>"><img src="/images/noimage.png" alt="no image" /></a>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

        </div>
        <div class="post-info">
            <span class="post-info-left">
            #<a href="#" class="postid"><?php echo($id); ?></a> by <?php if (!empty($name)){
            echo(substr($name, 0, 8));
            }else{
            echo("norseman");
            }
            ?>
            </span>
            <span class="post-info-right">
            <?php echo($timestamps); ?>
            </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
            <div class="post-preview">
                <?php echo(substr($textcontent, 0, 150)); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And here is the time_passed() function:

```
function time_passed($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
    }
```

So my guess is that for every new "while", it edits all of the timestamps. I just don't know how to fix this, considering the string is inside an `while()` statement.

EDIT:
I noticed my timestamp updated because I altered the bump row on every post each time a new thread was posted, this way all the timestamps were updated. I fixed the timestamp row now.

Comment: "edits all of the timestamps"? Not possible. not unless your query was returning the same timestamp for all the result rows. each call to time_passed would create a NEW DT object set, not re-use ones from previous calls.

Comment: @MarcB Well it does. http://i.imgur.com/ZFvnBqG.png  and the code for the time_passed function (and calling it) is exactly the same as on that image. - And I checked the DB to make sure the timestamps were different and they are.

Comment: well, what are the timestamp values that you're passing in? if it's something non-standard that datetime can't parse (it is basically just doing `strtotime()` internally), and your timestamps are all relatively close to each other, the bits that CAN be parsed would all come out the same.

Comment: 2014-09-09 19:10:54, 2014-09-08 17:10:48, 2014-09-09 16:32:10 are a few examples @MarcB

Comment: works fine here. for your `19:10:54` timestamp, I get "5 hours ago".

Comment: @MarcB did you do several entries in a while statement?

Comment: `echo time_passed('2014-09-09 19:10:54'), time_passed('2014-09-08  17:10:48', time_passed('2014-09-09 16:32:10'));` gives me `5 hours ago20 hours, 55 minutes, 53 seconds ago`. And doing this in aw hile loop would make no difference. none of your variables inside the function are static, none have been declared global, so they exist in their own little universe and exist only while the function is executing.

Comment: @MarcB Weird. Very weird. Does it have anything to do with the function being outside of the while?

Comment: nope. a while loop wouldn't change anything. `foo(1);foo(1);foo(1)` would execute no differently than `while($i++<=3){foo(1);}` or `for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { foo (1); }`

Comment: @MarcB Still not working... this is so strange. I swear my code is no different from what I wrote.

Comment: @MarcB I added the whole `while`to the question now

Comment: @MarCB It might also be worth mentioning that the function is include()ed as well as the post template into another file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your time_passed routine is expecting a datetime - not a timestamp, perhaps that is the error.

```
function time_passed($datetime, $full = false) {
```

Try to change this line:

```
$ago = new DateTime($datetime);
```

to this:

```
$ago = new DateTime(date('r',$datetime));
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: That turned them all to 44 years ago

Comment: @keith: -1. `date()` expects a php/unix timestamp as its second arg. passing in a string is useless and will produce a default `0` timestamp. DateTime() is very flexible in its constructor, and will pass arbitrary strings through (basically) strtotime()

Comment: Hi impedans , I'm here to help again - please check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this again ... since they are all coming out the same, it sounds like the value you are passing to the function is wrong then - try putting a a test around the timestamp assignment:

```
$timestamps = $rowaaa['timestamp'];
echo "Made |$timestamps| from |{$rowaaa['timestamp']}<br/>\n";
$timestamps = time_passed($timestamps);
echo "Now timestamps is |$timestamps| from time_passed() function<br/>\n";
```

If they are all the same, the problem is in your data.

You can also show the entire content of the array by doing this:

```
echo "Full Details<pre>\n".print_r($rowaaa,1)."\n</pre>\n";
```